# tsqlt.runall results in several 'mismatching number of begin and commit statement errors'

Tags: tsqlt

When running my first unit test with tSQLt, I'm getting several error messages all containing the phrase 'Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements.'

The error messages don't name my test procedure as the culprit, but rather the following procedures native to tSQLt :

Private_RunTest
Private_RunTestClass
Private_RunCursor
Private_RunAll
Private_RunMethodHandler
RunAll

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you update the question to include the definition of your test and the definition of the object under test.

Comment: are you faking synonym?